# Error handling with (boost::)outcome : use in constructor with composition and inheritance

Tags: c++, boost, error-handling, c++17

In my environment I cannot use exceptions so I need an alternative solution for error-handling. Returning an int as the error code is not a good way in a new modern project because this interface prevents to return other data.

std::expected is not yet available; maybe there are some sample implementations but I need something already tested and robust.

I'm evaluating (boost::)outcome https://ned14.github.io/outcome/ and it seems to fit my needs: it has a clear interface and it should be very efficient if no auxiliary payloads are used.

The use case for generic class method is quite simple: https://ned14.github.io/outcome/tutorial/essential/result/

Regarding the usage with constructors, the author suggests a dual phase construction (https://ned14.github.io/outcome/tutorial/advanced/constructors/).

The tutorial does not talk about class composition and inheritance. The following example is the same as the tutorial.

```
class A {
protected: // use protected because of C class in the next example
    constexpr A() noexcept { /*...*/ }
public:
    ~A() noexcept { /*...*/ }

    A( A&& rhs ) noexcept { /*...*/ }

    A& operator=( A&& rhs ) noexcept 
    {
        this->~A();
        new(this) A( std::move( rhs ) );
        return *this;
    }

    // Remove copy ctor and assignment op
    A( const A& ) = delete;
    A& operator=( const A& ) = delete;

    /** Static member constructor */
    static result<A> A_ctor() noexcept 
    {
        // Phase 1 ctor
        A ret;
        // Phase 2 ctor
        if ( /*something goes wrong*/ ) return MyErrorCode::Error;
        return { std::move( ret ) };
    }

    void a_method() noexcept { /*...*/ }
};

template<> struct make<A>
{
    result<A> operator()() const noexcept
    {
        return A::A_ctor();
    }
};
```

Now consider the class B that contains the class A. Being A ctor protected, the following declaration is not valid:

```
class B {
    A a_;
    ...
};
```

Maybe the following could work:

```
class B {
    result<A> a_;
    constexpr B() noexcept : a_( make<A>{}() ) {}
public:
    static result<B> B_ctor() noexcept
    {
        // Phase 1 ctor
        B ret;
        // Phase 2 ctor
        if ( ret.value().a_.has_failure() ) return MyErrorCode::Error;
        if ( /*something else goes wrong*/ ) return MyErrorCode::AnotherError;
        return { std::move( ret ) };
    }

    // ...

    void b_method() noexcept
    {
        a_.value().a_method(); // <-- ugly!
        // ...
    }
};
```

but using `result<A>` as type for `a_` is not very nice. It requires to use `a_.value()` everywhere in the code where `a_` is used. Moreover if `a_` is often used, efficiency could be reduced. Is there any other solution?

There's another dark point with derived classes.

```
class C : public A {
    constexpr C() noexcept : A() { /*...*/ }
public:
    // ...

    static result<C> C_ctor() noexcept
    {
        // Phase 1 ctor
        C ret;
        // Phase 2 ctor
        // How to reuse A ctor???
        // ...
        return { std::move( ret ) };
    }
};
```

In `C_ctor` I would like to construct the class starting from `A_ctor` to avoid code duplication, something like:

```
result<C> ret = C::A_ctor();
```

but there's no available conversion. Any idea to solve this point?

Comment: If the `B` default constructor is private, can you just remove it? Store an `A` directly in `B` and have a constructor `B::B(A&&)` which you only call if `A_ctor` is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Being A ctor protected, the following declaration is not valid.

You cannot indeed use non-accessible constructors, but move constructor is public,
so you might write your `X_ctor` differently:

```
B(A&& a) noexcept : a_(std::move(a)) {} // use public A(A&&)

static result<B> B_ctor() noexcept
{
    result<A> a = make<A>(); 
    if ( a.has_failure() ) return MyErrorCode::Error;

    // Phase 1 ctor
    B ret(std::move(a.value()));

    // Phase 2 ctor
    if ( /*something else goes wrong*/ ) return MyErrorCode::AnotherError;
    return { std::move( ret ) };
}
```

> In C_ctor I would like to construct the class starting from A_ctor to avoid code duplication

You might have `init` functions:

```
result<bool> init() noexcept 
{
    // ...
    if ( /*something goes wrong*/ ) return MyErrorCode::Error;
    return {true};
}

static result<A> A_ctor() noexcept 
{
    // Phase 1 ctor
    A ret;
    // Phase 2 ctor
    result<bool> a_init = ret.init();
    if ( a_init.has_failure() ) return a_init.error();
    return { std::move( ret ) };
}
```

and

```
result<bool> init() noexcept 
{
    result<bool> a_init = A::init();
    if ( a_init.has_failure() ) return a_init.error();

    // ...
    if ( /*something goes wrong*/ ) return MyErrorCode::Error;
    return {true};
}

static result<C> C_ctor() noexcept
{
    // Phase 1 ctor
    C ret;

    // Phase 2 ctor
    result<bool> c_init = ret.init();
    if ( c_init.has_failure() ) return c_init.error();
    return { std::move( ret ) };
}
```

Comment: I've used your advice, @Jarod42, and it seems to work. My doubt is the interface for creating objects into the heap (see `create_ptr` static ctor and `make_ptr` template). Are there any more elagant and efficient solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of @Jarod42 I solved with the following architecture.

**Base class:**

```
class A {
public:
    /** Static ctor */
    static inline result<A> create( size_t size ) noexcept
    {
        if ( size <= 0 ) return CncErrorCode::InvalidData;
        // Phase 1
        A ret;
        // Phase 2
        // ...
        if ( /* some error */ ) return CncErrorCode::GenericError;
        /*.*/
        return { std::move( ret ) };
    }

    /** Static ctor */
    static inline result<A*> create_ptr( size_t size ) noexcept
    {
        if ( size <= 0 ) return CncErrorCode::InvalidData;
        // Phase 1
        A* ret = new(std::nothrow) A();
        if ( ret == nullptr ) return CncErrorCode::NoMemory;
        // Phase 2
        // ...
        if ( /* some error */ ) return CncErrorCode::GenericError;
        /*.*/
        return ret;
    }
private:
    // Some private data here
private:
    constexpr A() noexcept { /* ... */ }
public:
    ~A() noexcept { /* ... */ }

    /** Move ctor */
    constexpr A( A&& rhs ) noexcept { /* ... */ }

    /** Move op */
    A& operator=( A&& rhs ) noexcept
    {
        if ( this != &rhs )
        {
            this->~A();
            new( this ) A( std::move( rhs ) );
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Remove copy ctor and assignment op
    A( const A& ) = delete;
    A& operator=( const A& ) = delete;
public:
    // public interface here
};

template<> struct make<A>
{
    size_t _size;

    result<A> operator()() const noexcept
    {
        return A::create( _size );
    }
};

template<> struct make_ptr<A>
{
    size_t _size;

    result<A*> operator()() const noexcept
    {
        return A::create_ptr( _size );
    }
};
```

**Composition use case:**

```
class B {
public:
    /** Static ctor */
    static result<B> create( size_t size ) noexcept
    {
        result<A> a = make<A>{ size }();
        if ( !a ) return a.as_failure();
        /*.*/
        return { std::move( B( std::move( a.value() ) ) ) };
    }

    /** Static ctor */
    static result<B*> create_ptr( size_t size ) noexcept
    {
        result<A> a = make<A>{ size }( );
        if ( !a ) return a.as_failure();
        B* ret = new(std::nothrow) B( std::move( a.value() ) );
        if ( ret == nullptr ) return CncErrorCode::NoMemory;
        /*.*/
        return ret;
    }
private:
    A a_;
private:
    constexpr B( A&& a ) noexcept : a_( std::move( a ) ) {}
public:
    /** Move ctor */
    constexpr B( B&& rhs ) noexcept : a_( std::move( rhs.a_ ) ) {}

    /** Move op */
    B& operator=( B&& rhs ) noexcept
    {
        if ( this != &rhs )
        {
            this->~B();
            new( this ) B( std::move( rhs ) );
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Remove copy ctor and assignment op
    B( const B& ) = delete;
    B& operator=( const B& ) = delete;
};

template<> struct make<B>
{
    size_t _size;

    result<B> operator()() const noexcept
    {
        return B::create( _size );
    }
};

template<> struct make_ptr<B>
{
    size_t _size;

    result<B*> operator()() const noexcept
    {
        return B::create_ptr( _size );
    }
};
```

**Inheritance use case:**

```
class C : public A {
public:
    /** Static ctor */
    static result<C> create( size_t size ) noexcept
    {
        result<A> base = make<A>{ size }();
        if ( !base ) return base.as_failure();
        /*.*/
        return { std::move( C( std::move( base.value() ) ) ) };
    }

    /** Static ctor */
    static result<C*> create_ptr( size_t size ) noexcept
    {
        result<A> base = make<A>{ size }();
        if ( !base ) return base.as_failure();
        C* ret = new(std::nothrow) C( std::move( base.value() ) );
        if ( ret == nullptr ) return CncErrorCode::NoMemory;
        /*.*/
        return ret;
    }
private:
    constexpr C( A&& base ) noexcept : A( std::move( base ) ) {}
public:
    /** Move ctor */
    constexpr C( C&& rhs ) noexcept : A( std::move( rhs ) ) {}

    /** Move op */
    C& operator=( C&& rhs ) noexcept
    {
        if ( this != &rhs )
        {
            this->~C();
            new( this ) C( std::move( rhs ) );
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Remove copy ctor and assignment op
    C( const C& ) = delete;
    C& operator=( const C& ) = delete;
};

template<> struct make<C>
{
    size_t _size;

    result<C> operator()() const noexcept
    {
        return C::create( _size );
    }
};

template<> struct make_ptr<C>
{
    size_t _size;

    result<C*> operator()() const noexcept
    {
        return C::create_ptr( _size );
    }
};
```

**Usage:**

```
auto b_r = make<B>{21}();
if ( b_r.has_error() )
{
    if ( b_r.error() == CncErrorCode::NoMemory ) { /* ... */ }
    else { /* ... */ }
}
B& b = b_r.value(); // Get an alias to the value
// ...

auto c_r = make_ptr<C>{53}();
if ( c_r.has_error() ) { /* ... */ }
C* c = c_r.value(); // Get an alias to the value
// ...
delete c;
```